# where should I implement security/Authorization in n-tier architecture?

Tags: security, architecture, authorization, n-tier-architecture, n-layer

where should I implement security/Authorization in n-tier architecture?

I was developing an ASP.Net MVC Application using N-tier Architecture. Should I implement the authorization module as a different layer or as Service?

Some Business rule depends on the User Role also, So what is the best way to implement Security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an n-tier application, no matter the technology (C#, java...), you probably want to externalize authorization altogether to a different service as you mention yourself. There is a standard that does that called [XACML](http://oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) (eXtensible Access Control Markup Language). It gives you

- an architecture
- a policy language
- a request/response scheme

With XACML, you can apply fine-grained authorization (i.e. authorization that takes into account the user, the resource, and additional context metadata) to all your app's layers: the presentation layer (to show/hide or enable/disable widgets), the web tier (to control access to web apps, urls, web services, APIs), the business tier, and even the database tier itself. I call that the anywhere architecture.

The benefit of XACML is that it's not specific to your .NET environment. This means you can leverage it in other environments.

I actually presented that topic last week at a Java developer conference. You can check out my presentation on [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/DavidBrossard/authorization-its-not-just-about-who-you-are).

HTH